# How to resolve XSRF Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) in API controller after SAST Checkmarx

Tags: java, spring-boot, csrf, checkmarx, secure-coding

I have done the scan my project java spring boot with Checkmarx tool.
The tool found about 23 XSRF occurrences with Medium severity.

The issue found is marked on Rest API method POST on `@RequestBody List<String> lineups`

In attached the screen-shoot for description result:

[image]

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/rules/lineup/{ruleMode}", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getRulesByRuleModeAndLineup(@PathVariable Integer ruleMode,
            @RequestBody List<String> lineups) throws Exception {
        
        LOGGER.info("[getRulesByRuleModeAndLineup] ENTER type: " + ruleMode + " lineup: " + lineups);
        
        ResponseEntity<Object> output = null;
        List<Rule> rules = new ArrayList<Rule>();

        try {
            
            for (String lineup : lineups) {
                
                String lineupSanitized = HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(lineup);
                rules.addAll(uiService.getRulesByRuleModeAndLineup(ruleMode, lineupSanitized));

            }

            output = new ResponseEntity<>(rules, HttpStatus.OK);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            LOGGER.error(e, e);
            output = new ResponseEntity<>("An error occurred: " + e.getMessage() + "'",
                    HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);

        }

        return output;

    }
```

Is there sample fix to resolve the issue ?

Comment: The message seems to explain the problem quite well: there is a user-supplied parameter that appears to be used unsafely in that method. How can you use it safely or discard the error? Only you can know, because only you can see the source-code of the method where it is handled. If you do not show us that code, there is little that readers can do.

Answer (score 2):

You can choose to have a validation on that field.
Here you have two choices:

1. use a framework that has this already build in, i recommend spring
   for this:
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/csrf.html
2. try to whitelist what strings you want to accept on your api, if you
   can do that.

The second one means you take the responsibility to keep your list up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to implement the first point that you told in your answer like followed code

**Back-end** side:

```
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
    import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);
    
        
        @SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
            
            http.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            
            http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity();
        }
    
    }
```

**Front-end** side

I implemented a xhrRequestHandler file name js inside the followed code:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function () {
    this.origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    if (document.cookie) {
        var csrfToken = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(`XSRF-TOKEN=([^;]+)`))[1];
        if (csrfToken) {
            this.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken);
        }
    }
    if (arguments[1].includes("socket/info")) {
        this.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    }
};
```

and on the index.jsp

I imported file js defined above with the followed code:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/xhrRequestHandler.js"/>"></script>
```

And added meta names rows:

```
<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

but I didn't resolve the issue

Is there something wrong ?